Getting NoClassDefFound Error org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException$NoNodeException while using solr-solrj-8.11.3
I have a java app which uses solrj jar to communicate to apache solr 8 and 9. Recently due to security vulnerabilities in solr-solrj-6.6.1.jar i upgraded to solr-solrj-8.11.3.jar. Compilation was successfull. But at runtime i'm unable to get any collections and could see these logs in my java app logs.
This is the excerpt of the java app log :
2024-05-15; 16:03:40.800 ***** exception: (hash:376089095) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException$NoNodeException
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:698)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:225)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:242)

Earlier when using solr-solrj-6.6.1 jar i did not encounter this error. I can see that the zookeeper jar is present in the solr directory.
I'm using my custom configsets which i place in the solr directory . All configuration to solr from my java app is given through my java app UI.
I also dont see any indexes being created.

I tried adding the zookeeper.jar in my java app library and this error seems to go off, but new errors popped up which im trying to figure.
Having said that my core question still reamains . Upgrading the solr-solrj-8.11.3.jar doesnt go smooth when integrating my java app to communicate to Apache Solr8/9

The integration of  Solr 8.8.1 and Solr 9.2.0 was successful with my Java app ( my java app lib containing Solrj-8.11.3 - I had to include zookeeper-3.9.2 to get rid of the NoClassDefFound errors mentioned above.
Albeit the same setup doesn't work with Solr latest 8.11.3 and 9.3.0,9.4.0,9.5.0,9.6.0
